# How do I update the React-DND drag preview based on where it is hovering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

What I have is a a table where I want to be able to drag and drop both the order of the rows and change their parents. Very similar to [this Kendo widget](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/dragdrop).

I have the drop operations themselves working, both changing parents and sorting, but I'm having trouble understanding how I can create previews to show the user what would happen when they drop.

As best as I can tell, the drag preview is set in the drag source's `componentDidMount`, but I'm not sure just how to wire the image up here in the source with the hover method in the target.

Comment: You can try something like this https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/issues/228 if you are using a custom drag layer, without custom layer(on browser generated preview image) this cannot be done.

Comment: @Arjun thanks. I'll take a look.